# Jest mocking of node-fetch calls the real fetch instead of the mock

Tags: node.js, jestjs, mocking, ts-jest

I have a simple controller which does a search with node-fetch. However, when I mock node-fetch, the fetch calls the real one in the controller.  Here is my code structure.
Why is the mock not effective? How can I solve this?

```js
            class ProductController {
              searchProduct = async (req: Request, resp: Response, next: NextFunction) => 
              {
                const { name, category} = req.body
                const request = { 
                  name: name, 
                 category: category
                }
                const response = await fetch('https://tradvent.com/products/search', {
                  method: 'post',
                  body: JSON.stringify(request),
                  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                })
                const data: any = await response.json()
                return data
              }   
            }
```

```js
          
           jest.mock('node-fetch')
           import fetch from 'node-fetch';


         describe('Product Search  Suite, () =>{
           
            it('test search' () =>{
            const req = {
              name: 'abc',
              category: 'deluxe'
           } 
            

            const response = {
            productCode: '123',
            category: 'deluxe',
            instock: true,
             ...
            }
              
           (fetch as jest.Mock).mockImplementation( () =>
             Promise.resolve(new Response(JSON.stringify(response)))
            );
           // calls the real fetch instead of fetch mock
           const  data = await  searchProduct(req)
           expect(data)toEqual(response)
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was correct, II just made a mistake on the fetch